Must a nonabelian group of odd order always have a normal Sylow subgroup?
Let $G$ be a nonabelian group of odd order $n = |G|$ that's not a prime power, so that all the Sylow subgroups are proper. Must it have at least one normal Sylow subgroup?
Of course this $G$ is solvable so it does have a proper nontrivial normal subgroup of some kind. Oddness of $n$ is needed because of $S_4$, all of whose Sylows are non-normal. We know that when $n$ is squarefree, $G$ has a normal $p$-subgroup for $p$ the largest prime factor of $n$. I also found a peculiar lemma that uses characters [Lemma 1.8 in https://engine.scichina.com/doi/pdf/396a8aaba08a40498525a10953675f12], stating that if $n$ is odd and has no factor $q^4$ ($q$ prime), then a normal Sylow must exist.
Any hints or pointers appreciated.

If $G$ has odd order then it is solvable; if it has a normal Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$, then $P$ has a complement by Hall's Theorem, so $G$ is a semidirect product of $P$ by a group of order prime to $p$. So the question is whether there are any odd-order groups that are not a semidirect product of a $p$-group by a $p'$-group.

The answer is no. The smallest example $G$ is the group with index [1053,51] in the SmallGroup library. (Note that $1053=3^4\cdot 13$.)
(In fact, that's the only example up to order $2000$.)
$G$ has the form $G=C_3^3\rtimes (C_{13}\rtimes C_3)$, with $C_3^3$ being self-centralising, so $C_{13}\rtimes C_3$ acts faithfully on it. (Didn't check how exactly.) $G$ only has four normal subgroups, all obvious from that form.

Wow, thanks very much, @verret.

My guess is that the action is the following. We can identify $C_3^3$ as the 3-dimensional vector space over $K=\Bbb{F}3$, its automorphisms coming from invertible 3x3 matrices over $K$. A copy of the extension field $F=\Bbb{F}{3^3}$ exists in there, and its multiplicative group is cyclic of order $26$ and therefore also a copy of $C_{13}$. Furthermore, the Galois group of $F/K$ is cyclic of order three, and its action comes from conjugations inside the normalizer $N(F^*)$ (by Skolem-Noether, though that is likely overkill).
